# Get value of select form

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to access the value of a select value with php.
The select gets it's options from a database.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
        Product:<br>
        <input type="text" name="product"><br>
        Category:<br>
        <select name="category">
            <?php
                $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT name FROM inventory_category");
                while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo "<option value=\"Category\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select><input type="submit" name="submit"></form>

<?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $name = $_POST['product'];
                $category = $_POST['category'];
                echo $name;
                echo '<br>';
                echo $category;?>
```

I get the expected result for `product` but not for `category` which displays as `Category` instead of the option selected.

I'm using this as a debug but ultimately I will be storing these chosen values to the database. Is there any difference to how to handle both situations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `value` is what is passed through to the PHP. Where you have `$row['name']` is only what is displayed on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `value` with the data you want:

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row['name']."\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
```